# Is there a way to get "people reached" sum across entire network for a user?

Tags: support, profile-page, personal-statistics

The New Model profiles on Meta.SE (pretty big improvement!) have a section for "[People reached](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here)" stat.

Now, unless I'm much mistaken, **that stat is specific to a given site on the network**.

If that assumption is indeed correct, **is there a way to find out the "People Reached" summary across 100% of the sites on the network for all your connected profiles**?

Comment: Before someone asks, [it's NOT on my SE central profile page that I can find](http://stackexchange.com/users/41067/dvk).

Comment: I think this would be really cool to see.

Comment: At this point will award bounty to anyone who posts an external tool that does this (e.g. a userscript, website, or SEDE query)

Comment: Hopefully, when [my question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254142/will-the-stackexchange-com-network-profile-get-an-update-that-corresponds-with-t) is addressed, you'll get this feature as well :)

Comment: It would be really cool to have a graph over time, like for reputation, too.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As indicated in the comments a SEDE query would do so [here it is](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/305411/is-there-a-way-to-get-people-reached-sum-across-entire-network-for-a-user?accountid=281857):

To run it you need your accountid and that one can be found by visiting your network account on StackExchange.com and then take the id from the url. Yours is [41067](https://stackexchange.com/users/41067/dvk), mine is [281857](https://stackexchange.com/users/281857/rene) and  Annonomus Penguin is [1640390](https://stackexchange.com/users/1640390/annonomus-penguin).

```sql
---- accountid: Account on stackexchnage.com ! "In the url on stackexchange.com"

-- create url from dbname
IF OBJECT_ID ( '#siteurl', 'P' ) IS NOT NULL 
    DROP PROCEDURE #siteurl;
GO

create procedure #siteurl
   @dbname nvarchar(250),
   @res nvarchar(250) OUT
   as
   begin
      declare @pos integer
      declare @rec nvarchar(250)
      set @res = @dbname
      set @pos = CHARINDEX('.', @dbname)
      if (@pos > 0 ) 
      begin
         set @rec = substring(@dbname, @pos+1, len(@dbname))
         exec #siteurl @rec,  @rec output
         set @res = @rec 
                  + '.' 
                  + substring(@dbname, 0, @pos) 
      end
   end;
go

declare @accountid int = ##accountid:int##  -- 93484

-- all databases
declare  db_c cursor for select [name] 
                         from sys.databases 
                         where database_id > 5 -- skip master, temp, model, msdb, Data.SE
                     
declare @db_c_name sysname   -- holds name of db after fetch
declare @sql nvarchar(max) -- holds build up sql string

-- result table
create table #all_reached ( site nvarchar(250)
                            , userid int
                            , displayname nvarchar(50)
                            , reached bigint);
                            
open db_c
fetch next from db_c into @db_c_name
while(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
begin
    set @sql = N'use '+ QUOTENAME(@db_c_name) +';
declare @url nvarchar(250)
exec #siteurl ''' + @db_c_name  + ''', @url output
declare @userid int = null
declare @displayname nvarchar(50)
select @userid = id 
     , @displayname = displayname
from users where accountid =  '+ cast(@accountid as nvarchar) + '
if @userid is not null 
begin
insert into #all_reached
select @url
     , @userid
     , @displayname
     , sum(isnull(p.viewcount,0))
from posts p
inner join (
  Select Id 
  From Posts 
  Where PostTypeId = 1 
  and owneruserid = @userid
  Union
  Select ParentId
    From Posts
   Where PostTypeId = 2
     And Id in (select AcceptedAnswerId from Posts)
     and owneruserid = @userid
  Union
  Select ParentId
    From Posts
   Where PostTypeId = 2
     And Score > 5
     and owneruserid = @userid
  Union
  Select a.ParentId
    From Posts a
         Join Posts q On a.ParentId = q.Id
   Where a.PostTypeId = 2
     And a.Score > 0.20 * (select sum(Score) from Posts where ParentId=q.Id)
     And a.Score > 0
     and a.owneruserid = @userid
  Union
  Select x.ParentId
    From (Select a.ParentId, Rank() Over(Partition By a.ParentId Order By ta.Score Desc) AnswerRank
            From Posts a
                 Join Posts ta On ta.ParentId = a.ParentId
           Where a.PostTypeId = 2
             And a.Score > 0
             and a.owneruserid = @userid
          ) x
          Where AnswerRank <= 3) 
rp on rp.id = p.id
end;'
               
    exec (@sql)
   fetch next from db_c into @db_c_name
end;
close db_c;
deallocate db_c;

select 'all ' as [site]
      , 'networkwide' as [display name]
      , sum(reached)
from #all_reached
union all
select replace(site,'.StackExchange','') as [site]
     , 'http://' 
     + site 
     + '.com/'
     + 'users'
     + '/'
     + cast(userid as nvarchar)
     + '|'
     + displayname
     , reached
from #all_reached
order by 3 desc

drop table #all_reached
```

This query uses the technique described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238650/158100) to iterate over all databases in SEDE. In the cursor loop I execute this [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/305409) for each single database and add the results to the temporary table #all_reached. After all databases are processed a select over that temp-table produces this result:

[image: people reached network wide]

Notice that there is [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253579/include-the-people-reached-and-helpful-flags-count-data-in-sede/253596#253596) to include the statistic in the users table so this query wouldn't require that much resources to run.

Comment: For some reason it says I've reached 382k people on GD SE when my profile says 273k, any idea why that is?

Comment: I blame caching ... mine was slightly lower so I expect the actual used query might be a little bit different than we can accomplish with SEDE.

Comment: Typo: The box where you enter your accountID says `Account on stackexchnage.com` and should be `Account on stackexchange.com` (swap the a and the n)

Comment: Any idea why the query suddenly broke for me? I had 950K a few weeks ago, and I ran it again today, and now it says I have only around 400K. When I added them together my top sites manually, I got in the 900K range.

Comment: @AnonymousPenguin the statistic can be very jumpy, specially on highly viewed questions where you have an answer that is on the edge of either being included or not. A new answer or a single down vote does a lot of damage. Also the data you looked at was a week old, while your manually check is live data. SEDE was refreshed 43 minutes ago (when I post this comment) Also the actual implementation serverside might slightly differ.

Comment: @rene I ran it again this morning (after the update today) and it's back to 950K. *shrugs.* Anyway, thanks for your hard work on this query!

Comment: Unfortunately, several years later, this times out.

Comment: @Rob Yeah, I have the feeling an index went missing / the size of the db is so large that multi-db with stackoverflow in the mix is no longer feasible :/