# Include the "People Reached" and "Helpful Flags (count)" data in SEDE

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, helpful-flags, people-reached

I know the new profile design hasn't been updated for [every site](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/04/two-new-user-pages-one-new-stat-this-ones-big) on the network yet, so maybe this is a bit too early. Nonetheless, please include the "People Reached" data in [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) at your earliest convenience.

Also, I was just made aware that users helpful flag counts are now publicly displayed on their [activity page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/152859/shadow-wizard?tab=topactivity) towards the top-right, underneath the people reached stat. So please include this data in SEDE as well.

Comment: Well, it can be calculated with a custom query - I know someone who will gladly write such a query... ;)

Comment: No idea who that could be @ShadowWizard

Comment: @rene we're so lucky Mr. Roomba doesn't visit our secret room... :D

Comment: It can be calculated for a site by a custom query, but having the field in the data dump would help with cross-site/multi-site queries (like "how many people have I helped, everywhere?").

Answer (score 31):

I fully support this request. If you don't mind hammer the SEDE database you can use [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/301740) that I [forked](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/253267/people-helped-public-prototype-1?UserId=811) from the [original post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here).

```
select top 100 
       sum(isnull(p.viewcount,0)) as reached
     , rp.owneruserid as [User Link]
from posts p
inner join (
  Select Id, OwnerUserId 
  From Posts 
  Where PostTypeId = 1 
  and owneruserid is not null
  Union
  Select ParentId, OwnerUserId
    From Posts
   Where PostTypeId = 2
     And Id in (select AcceptedAnswerId from Posts)
     and owneruserid is not null
  Union
  Select ParentId, OwnerUserId
    From Posts
   Where PostTypeId = 2
     And Score > 5
     and owneruserid is not null
  Union
  Select a.ParentId, a.OwnerUserId
    From Posts a
         Join Posts q On a.ParentId = q.Id
   Where a.PostTypeId = 2
     And a.Score > 0.20 * (select sum(Score) from Posts where ParentId=q.Id)
     And a.Score > 0
     and a.owneruserid is not null
  Union
  Select x.ParentId, x.OwnerUserId 
    From (Select a.ParentId , a.OwnerUserId, Rank() Over(Partition By a.ParentId, a.OwnerUserId Order By ta.Score Desc) AnswerRank
            From Posts a
                 Join Posts ta On ta.ParentId = a.ParentId
           Where a.PostTypeId = 2
             And a.Score > 0
             and a.owneruserid is not null
          ) x
          Where AnswerRank <= 3) 
rp on rp.id = p.id
group by rp.owneruserid
order by sum(isnull(p.viewcount,0)) desc
```

I removed the per user where clause in all union sub queries so you can analyze people reached over the complete community. This query does output results but it takes a while:

[image: people reached SEDE output]

Comment: Small follow-up question. The query in the answer above returns the value for at most top 50000 users (after which the execution times out). I couldn't find the "people_reached" data in the data dump/SEDE. Is there a way to get this value for all users?

Comment: @madman_with_a_box SEDE [never returns more then 50000 rows](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234774/158100)

Comment: Unfortunately the query returns a "Execution Timeout Expired." error, because in the past four years we've grown. It would be great if there was a way to rewrite so it looked at the top Q&A writers (whom *probably*, but not absolutely positively) have the most views and merge with the most viewed Q&A's to reduced the size of what is looked at (giving a chance to complete within the allowed time). --- Alternatively, if we could specify our own main ID (and possibly a comma separated list of several others) and simply get *that* answer. As-is this query is only of historical interest. Thanks.