# Can we sort users by impact?

Tags: feature-request, users-page, people-reached

With the recent release of the [new profile](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/04/two-new-user-pages-one-new-stat-this-ones-big/?cb=1), we received the impact stat.

[image: impact box]

It would be really cool to see all users listed by impact. Example:

[image: impact tab]

Add an impact tab to the Users page, and sort users by the approximate number of people reached during the given time frame. Although, it might not make sense to allow viewing impact by any time frame other than "all", as views are only counted, not recorded as time-based events.

---

Note: for reference, [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253579/include-the-people-reached-data-in-sede) requests the data be made available in SEDE.

Comment: You know that you circled their rep right?

Comment: @PythonMaster I do. I was too lazy to replace the numbers. Perhaps the circles are too distracting?

Comment: I wonder why we don't have this feature yet.  It can be of great relevance to Stack Overflow for Teams as well as the Enterprise version.