# Is the new statistics, number of people reached available in the data dump

Tags: discussion, data-dump, people-reached

I am interested to see how this new statistics motivate users to contribute. But in the data dump, this variable seems not to be in the data dump.

Comment: No, it is not but this [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253579/include-the-people-reached-and-helpful-flags-count-data-in-sede/253596#253596) of mine shows how you can calculate it your self.