# What is Views of users in the database schema documentation?

Tags: support, data-explorer, data-dump, views

In the [Database Schema Documentation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), what is the Views field for Users? It does not match the (estimated) "number of people reached" displayed for users on their profile page.

Comment: Number of profile views I'd guess.

Comment: Views on the profile page? Not the combined views on all the question and answer posts by the user?

Comment: Why should there be a sum that isn't used anywhere?

Comment: @madman_with_a_box no, that's the people reached aka impact. There's already [pending request to add it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253579/include-the-people-reached-and-helpful-flags-count-data-in-sede).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I feel that value could be an interesting one to observe.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, that's really helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/869018/number-of-views-for-user-181217): (Profile views)

> [image]

Keep in mind: SEDE data is updated only once a week so many times it won't be consistent.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to obtain the data for estimated number of people reached?

Comment: @madman_with_a_box yes, in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253596/152859)