# View "people reached" data/trend through time for user

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, users, people-reached

1. Is there a way to view a trend (graphically or tabulated) in the number of "people reached" per user per site?

   - E.g., to see how many people a user's posts impacted monthly or annually, etc.
2. Assuming there isn't currently a way to do this, can anyone propose a way to actually develop a SEDE query for accomplishing this?

   - It's not clear to me if this data is even able to be queried...

Comment: even viewing "historical" (past) values for this number would be interesting. E.g., viewing the number reached on XX-XX-XXXX date (or, more interesting, the total number reached *by* XX-XX-XXXX date)

Comment: see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253579/include-the-people-reached-and-helpful-flags-count-data-in-sede/253596#253596