# Will the stackexchange.com network profile get an update that corresponds with the new profile?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, network-profile

Upon visiting my [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current), I noticed it was not updated in the major profile update. Is it scheduled to get a face-lift as well?

As a sidenote, [it would be pretty awesome to see the sum of people reached from the various communities you contribute to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246194/is-there-a-way-to-get-people-reached-sum-across-entire-network-for-a-user) within this profile page.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Probably! But not very soon.**

As it happens, the project lead for this and I we were *just* discussing the network profile, and for this exact reason - letting people see their aggregate people reached.

We'd like to see this happen, but it's lower priority than getting a bunch of other stuff done, including the CSS updates on other sites, bugfixes, etc. and it's a little more work than it might look like, due to what's involved in SE.com pulling data from a bunch of other sites.

Comment: Will we get any preview of the intended design, or will it be a pleasant surprise one day in the not-so-near future? :-)

Comment: They'll have to preview it. How else will screenshots of my profile be shared with the world?!?!

Comment: How is the CSS update going anyway?

Comment: Almost two years later, any update?