# How can I sort my posts by impact/people reached?

Tags: support, people-reached

Since the new profile was introduced, there is a new stat for impact, which measures how many people you have reached (based on views of highest-voted answers on questions etc).

I've been a bit curious about my statistic, and I was wondering which of my posts contributed most of the views.

**So is there any way I see a list of my posts sorted by impact?**

Built in design features, search terms, [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) queries, or other methods are all appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ripped the per database query from [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254178/158100) and added the per question viewcount which gave me [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/358392/how-can-i-sort-my-posts-by-impact-people-reached?UserId=104515)

```sql
declare @userid int = ##userid:int##

select p.id as [Post Link]
     , p.viewcount
from posts p
inner join (
  Select Id 
  From Posts 
  Where PostTypeId = 1 
  and owneruserid = @userid
  Union
  Select ParentId
    From Posts
   Where PostTypeId = 2
     And Id in (select AcceptedAnswerId from Posts)
     and owneruserid = @userid
  Union
  Select ParentId
    From Posts
   Where PostTypeId = 2
     And Score > 5
     and owneruserid = @userid
  Union
  Select a.ParentId
    From Posts a
         Join Posts q On a.ParentId = q.Id
   Where a.PostTypeId = 2
     And a.Score > 0.20 * (select sum(Score) from Posts where ParentId=q.Id)
     And a.Score > 0
     and a.owneruserid = @userid
  Union
  Select x.ParentId
    From (Select a.ParentId, Rank() Over(Partition By a.ParentId Order By ta.Score Desc) AnswerRank
            From Posts a
                 Join Posts ta On ta.ParentId = a.ParentId
           Where a.PostTypeId = 2
             And a.Score > 0
             and a.owneruserid = @userid
          ) x
          Where AnswerRank <= 3) 
rp on rp.id = p.id
order by viewcount desc
```

Here is what the result looks like for you at the day of posting:

[image: post viewcount for people reached posts]

Comment: +1 Rene to the rescue... what took you so long? I pinged you about 10 hours ago :)

Comment: @HackerKarma yeah, tnx, I saw that but I have a job that pays me although  it does distract from participating here...

Comment: Got it...How hard will this be to run on other sites e.g. Meta.SE?

Comment: Easy you can switch the site using the selector under the run query button

Comment: Thanks - I assumed it would be a data exchange query.