# Total people reached in all SE sites combined ("global impact"), under network profile?

Tags: feature-request, network-profile, people-reached

The impact (people reached) infobox on the profile page is a motivating feature. Any plans adding a similar infobox on the network profile to display the total people reached across all SE sites?

Comment: Related and marked duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329927/i-have-reached-much-more-than-35k-people-where-can-i-see-all-my-stack-exchange

Answer (score 19):

In my opinion, not much people visit the network profile.

How about something like this in the [Communities] box instead, so whatever site profile you're viewing you will know the impact of the user:

[image]

More visibility, more motivation, and little space is required.

Answer (score 6):

Agreed 200% with [Heidel's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270098/total-people-reached-in-all-se-sites-combined-global-impact-under-network-p/270099#270099). For an easy and far reaching global statistic, that's a very good place: under "Communities" on every profile on any site account.

To get your global number, check [this answer by Rene (SEDE query)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246194/is-there-a-way-to-get-people-reached-sum-across-entire-network-for-a-user/254178#254178).

I guess the feature request in question here has a tiny audience, but I'm counting it's a tiny vip crowd that would fancy a lot to see something like this:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: This request seems to be asking for a total reach across the network, rather than a display of the already existing per-site calculation, but +1 anyway, because this picture is a great mock-up of exactly what I'm talking about in [this request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272615/add-impact-to-accounts-tab-of-network-profile)!

Comment: Hello. Please see my bounty given to improve this answer as I explained I think it should be improved. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Unlike rep, the total reaching is inaccurate. If you answer on a late, but popular question your total reaching will directly be up by that question reach.

Dont get me wrong, this is cool statistic, but as its inaccurate I dont see the need to give it more visibility.