# Add "Impact" to Accounts tab of Network Profile

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts, network-profile, people-reached

The Accounts tab of my Network Profile provides a convenient way to quickly compare my reputation, badges, and Q&A counts across all of the Stack Exchange sites I've linked together, but to compare my reach or other Impact stats, I have to open up each site profile individually, or run a lengthy [Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/305411/is-there-a-way-to-get-people-reached-sum-across-entire-network-for-a-user). I think that the "People Reached" stat would be a useful addition to the Accounts tab.

Note: I am not asking for a total "reach" value to be calculated (there's an [existing question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246194/287261) for that), but for the addition of a column to the Accounts tab showing the same "reach" values that are currently displayed on each individual profile page.

---

User brasofilo posted the following mock-up on [this answer to another meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279318/287261); I'm including it here because it's *precisely* what I'm suggesting. Note that unlike the requests for a network-wide total reach, which would require an evaluation of how to calculate that (e.g. *"we can't just add them all, or people who've viewed this user's posts on multiple sites will be counted multiple times"*), this request is just to place the already-existing statistic in another location.

<kbd>[![][1]][1]</kbd>

Comment: Meh. That statistic is largely useless.