# Network profile having info like a community profile

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, network-profile, personal-statistics

It'd be great to see a total of questions and answers (not only organized by community as we currently have in Network Profile > Accounts, and including Community Meta), top tags, people reached, like in profile a normal community profile except that it'd be network wide.

[image]

There's at least two requests that point to this desire

- [Network profile should list total reputation and badges across the network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136425/364217)
- [Total people reached in all SE sites combined ("global impact"), under network profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270098/364217)
- [Is there a way to get "people reached" sum across entire network for a user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246194/364217)

Comment: Related: [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304231/295232) to "Do we want to keep the network profile page?" - not sure if that's still the current stance of the company.