# Can some metadata about deleted posts be included in Data.SE?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-explorer, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

I like to use [Data.SE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to view usage stats for some of the sites, however deleted posts are not included on Data.SE and I think this skews the numbers quite a bit, particularly on sites with a lot of deletions.

Would it be possible to include some limited data about deleted posts in Data.SE to make statistical queries more accurate?

You could clear the non-public data fields of deleted posts, such as `Posts.Title`, `Posts.Body`, and `Posts.OwnerUserId` to address privacy concerns explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/136267/165773). You could even leave the `PostId` set to 0 since I know SE doesn't want to provide users with a way of searching deleted questions.

The data I would mostly be interested in is `CreationDate`, `LastActivityDate`, `PostHistory` (date closed, date reopened, date deleted, etc), and the fact there *was* a deleted question in the first place. Up/Down votes, Score, Tags, and View/Answer/Favorite count would also be preferred.

This would make the statistical queries accurate, while still removing the information not meant to be visible to the public.

Comment: I've been meaning to post this for quite a while. I would absolutely _love_ it if this were implemented.

Comment: "now that Data.SE is automated"...automation or not was never really a motivator for hiding deleted questions, evident by the fact they're consistently hidden everywhere.  We simply don't publish a list of deleted content (which you'd have by Id, with this request) anywhere.

Comment: @NickCraver Hrrmm I thought I saw a question like this a while back, and someone declined it because doing a data dump to Data.SE was a manual process and stripping non-public data would be too much of a bother.

Comment: Hmm, not directly related, but did you ever make a request for keeping successful close/reopen votes in the votes table? I was thinking the other day that the current behaviour is rather useless.

Comment: @TimStone [I have now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160981/158605) :)

Comment: @NickCraver - I understand the value of not exposing deleted content as it's generally crud with little to no redeeming value.  However, not having access to that information makes it difficult to identify behavioral patterns regarding the genesis of that content.  It's hard to suggest quality improvement when I can't definitively say where some of the crud is coming from.

Comment: Can you give some examples of the kind of statistics you're hoping to garner from this? I *suspect* I know what you're going for, but it's not entirely clear from what you're requesting.

Comment: @Shog9 I like to run queries on things like post activity and site usage over a time frame, and new user activity and retention rates. These can be very skewed without deleted posts, especially if the user had a bad start on the site. I've seen other users run statistical queries on Data.SE too, and keep having to remind them that deleted posts are not included. It wasn't a big deal in the past because deleted posts were such a small percentage, but with so many more closed posts now getting deleted with the tweaked auto-delete script, the numbers have shifted quite a bit.

Comment: @Rachel: actually, the tweaks aren't live yet - they're waiting on a huge pile of other changes that should be going out Real Soon Now. Of course, they *will* tend to skew things a tad when they *do* go live, so you may want to investigate whatever oddities you're observing before then.

Comment: @Shog9 Hrrmmm I thought the changes were live due to the number of posts deleted by Community on Programmers.SE recently

Comment: Well, there *are* two other auto-delete scripts that've been running weekly / monthly for years now...

Comment: @Shog9 I was re-running the queries displayed [here](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/3140/1130) and noticed a pretty dramatic shift in some of the numbers. Those were posted about a year ago. Around the same time I also noticed the Community user deleting a lot of older posts on Programmers, so thought the script had been updated. It may have just been coincidence though.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

## Yes

We've added a new table called `PostsWithDeleted` that includes metadata from all posts, including the deleted ones. If the post is deleted, we've nulled out all fields except:

- ID
- PostTypeId
- ParentId
- CreationDate
- DeletionDate
- Score
- Tags (*later added*)
- ClosedDate (*later added*)
- ContentLicense (*later added*)

That's helpful for doing meaningful research that requires looking at activity on the site without being biased by our aggressive deletion scripts.

As of right now on Stack Overflow, [that table shows](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/364933/stack-overflows-deleted-first-post?opt.textResults=true):

```
questions answers  posts    deleted extant_questions extant_answers 
--------- -------- -------- ------- ---------------- -------------- 
12779084  19666615 32519143 5576247 10133016         16736439
```

That lines up with the [current stats](https://stackoverflow.com/10m):

> Here's how far we've come together
>
> 10,159,316 programming questions
>
> 16,766,219 solutions given

Since the data in SEDE is from September 9 (`rev 2015.9.9.45`), it has a touch fewer posts in it's counts.

At the moment, there's no way to see the titles of deleted questions. Bodies and the various UserIds are also null for deleted posts, for obvious reasons. We also null out Views, LastEditDate, and LastActivityDate. However, I'm quite pleased with this new table as a way for us to be more transparent about the posts that *can't* be seen on the site.

Comment: Oh, so you don't get tags for deleted posts? Hmm, then that cheering was a bit premature.

Comment: Why are votes nulled? That seems it might be useful too?

Comment: @enderland: Well, as I mention in the answer, it's not hard to calculate Score from the Votes table if you are selecting a few posts. We might need to consider leaving Score denormalized if people end up using this table to look at the scores of deleted posts often.

Comment: @JonEricson I guess that works, thanks whoever made this a priority! It'll be fun I think to play with :D

Comment: @ChristianRau: My initial spec included tags, but that was taken out in the name of caution.

Comment: I updated the [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/158100) with this new table.

Comment: @JonEricson so, tags were considered somehow sensitive, right? would be interesting to learn why, I thought these were safe. I thought tags data could be useful for burnination / blacklisting but since it's unsafe, that's apparently not an option

Comment: It'd be nice to have the deletion user for these, we could analyze when spam hits by looking at thing deleted/locked by Community outside of the normal roomba-ing.s

Comment: @gnat: I sympathize with you. As I said, my initial spec included tags, which I think are both safe and useful. But somewhere in [this process](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/263675/1438) we decided to only include the five fields I listed above for deleted posts. That doesn't mean we can't add more fields in later. For the moment, we just want to be sure that we not releasing a djinn who refuses to get back in the jar.

Comment: I see, you released with least risk possible and keep your options open, that makes good sense indeed

Comment: @Undo You can do this with this data: VoteTypeId = 12 is spam flag.

Comment: @NormalHuman Whoa, I didn't know we included spam flags in the public data dump. Thanks!

Comment: @JonEricson If I remember correctly, votes on deleted posts were not previously included in the Votes table in SEDE. Now they are. Was this change simultaneous with the introduction of PostsWithDeleted, or did I miss something?

Comment: @NormalHuman: I was a bit surprised that votes for deleted posts existed, but I don't think they were added as a part of this change. From what I can tell looking at the revision history, votes on deleted post have been available since the beginning. (Don't hold me to that, however. I'm a bit rusty reading other people's code. ;)

Comment: Thanks so much!!! Now to find a weekend to brush up on my SQL skills to run some data analysis.... :D

Comment: @enderland: We recently began denormalizing Score for deleted posts.

Comment: Awesome - I'll have to play around with this sometime :)

Comment: @JonEricson: Is there any interest in adding other content related to deleted posts? Like votes, comments and flags? Again, for similar reasons mentioned in the OP and comments.

Comment: Is there any way an `OwnerUserId` could be added to the list of fields populated for the `PostsWithDeleted` table? I understand the concern about identifying the user, but without post content and title this info is relatively harmless. What's more, it could immensely help active users in helping others asking why they are question/answer banned without the need to involve a moderator.

Comment: @OlegValter:That should be a separate question. But I do think it's potentially  harmful because it would allow other people to turn up evidence of past behavior after the person has reformed.(See [why we don't publicly track suspensions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293213/why-we-dont-keep-public-records-of-suspensions).)

Comment: @JonEricson - yeah, I should probably make it a FR. I am quite unsure how suspensions and deleted posts are related (I've seen the Q&A before) and fail to grasp what harm can this information potentially do, though.

Comment: On stackoverflow I have 11k reputation and can thus see deleted posts with all their data. Why can't I see all their data in SEDE, even when I log in with my stackoverflow account?

Comment: @KellyBundy: I don't know the full reason and I no longer work at the company. But the core issue is that SEDE hasn't been actively worked on in years. It's a wonderful tool and I'm glad to have it. It's just not a priority for improvement.

Comment: @JonEricson Thanks. Yes, it's nice and I use it for some things. The [api](https://api.stackexchange.com) as well, since SEDE data sadly lags by a few days.