# Can we have a (useless) statistics site?

Tags: feature-request, statistics

Born [out of curiosity arose the question "what was the fastest closing (on Meta)?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175101/fatal-error-in-xampp?noredirect=1#comment-524510), but unfortunately that question is not easy to answer. So another idea formed in my mind...can we get a site (like `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/statistics/` or something) which displays useful, useless and curious data?

Something like (only numbers, no links):

- Question count
- Answer count
- User count
- Question with accepted answers (count and percentage)
- Fastest answer (from question posted to answer posted, self-answer obviously excluded)
- Fastest accepted answer
- Fastest close (with and without moderator intervention)
- Fastest deletion (self-deletion does not count, also with and without moderator intervention)
- Most flags on one post (count and what kind of post)
- and so on...

And yes, I know part of this is already exposed (on the site or on the Stack Exchange site list or in the Data Explorer). It's also more than enough if that page refreshes once every day...or every other for that. But it would be nice to have such statistics.

So, can we get that? ... Pretty please?

Comment: And you got the idea [from here (10K)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175101/fatal-error-in-xampp?noredirect=1#comment-524510)... +1

Comment: @hims056: Yeah...I did not link to it because I figured that question would be gone in a few minutes. But you're right.

Comment: Can't you get most of these stats on [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @Yannis: The explorer does not include deleted question, also there are timestamps of some actions missing. But yeah, you could got *some* from there.

Comment: Oh, what the hell, +1 useless stats are fun! ;)

Comment: I don't think "Fastest Accepted Answer" would work. I believe you have to wait 5(?) minutes before you can accept an answer. On one of the questions I asked on SO before I had a "you can accept this answer in *x* seconds" message - so I simply waited a little while. I imagine a lot of people have accepted right on the shortest possible time.

Comment: I'm afraid there would be people who would consider it another "badge" if they got their question to the statistics page.

Comment: @Juhana: I did not make it clear, yes, but I'd intentionally (for that reason) not provide links to items in question, only the numbers.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Well, I did accept an answer [within three seconds of it being posted](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/153248/timeline) on Meta once.

Comment: @TimStone - Correct. If any answer is posted after few minutes (5 minutes I think), you can accept it without any waiting.

Comment: It would be very interesting to see historical data, especially after changes in the SE engine or policies. Like: what is the influence of no longer showing accept rate on the overall accept rate? Or is that none of our business (I'm very curious though).

Comment: I have a MSO feature-request that is asking [for some meta data about deleted posts in SEDE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157462/158605). That would make queries like this possible

Comment: There are [some excellent statistics posts on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bstatistics%5D+votes%3A20+is%3Aq). They could be channeled into one site.