# Was a question ever closed with 5 different reasons?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Any time I open the close dialog I wonder if it ever happened that 5 people voted to close; each of them with a different reason?

As long as it wasn't done deliberately the probability of such lack of consensus is very low, but there are, on the other hand, millions of questions on SE so even a very improbable event can occur.

So, has it ever happened?

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com

Comment: Let's find out... To the data explorer!

Comment: Sure, I don't have a link, but I've seen it happen a few times, and simultaneously chuckled and slapped my forehead when it happens.

Comment: We've done it before from our chat rooms. The last close vote is the binding one. Time to find that screenie...

Comment: Why does it matter if it's ever happened?

Comment: Does anybody actually know MSSQL? I'm failing. `SELECT Id as [Post Link] FROM Posts
WHERE Posts.PostTypeId = 1 AND 5 = SELECT Count(*) FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT Comment FROM PostHistory
  WHERE Posts.Id = PostHistory.PostId
  AND PostHistory.PostHistoryTypeId = 10
)`

Comment: @Servy [Because we are all curious.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175118/can-we-have-a-useless-statistics-site)

Comment: related: [What happens if a fifth person chooses a different reason to close?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32700/165773) *Not* a dupe: "4 votes, 2 for one reason, 2 for other, and the fifth person chooses a third..." - that's different from what is asked here

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes it has happened before.

When 5 people vote to close with 5 different reasons, the last close vote is the one that is used to break the tie.

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11348463/duplicated-code-above-and-inside-while-loop

Screenshot prior to final close vote:

[image]

---

And here's where we discussed this in chat:

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/4401471#4401471

Comment: That's true.  So how many questions were closed with all five reasons?

Comment: Did I misread the question?

Comment: @RobertHarvey unfortunately I don't think that information is readily available. The data explorer doesn't seem to keep track of close vote reasons, only the votes themselves. I doubt that the data dumps have them either.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/114660/distribution-of-close-reasons.  Actually, I think it may only record the final close reason choice.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That query doesn't really tell us anything. Is just lists close votes. Not questions with 5 different close votes.

Comment: @Mysticial: Yes, but if it lists everyone's close vote, you can extrapolate the needed information.

Comment: Well, I've asked if it ever happened so it's fully valid answer. I don't understand the downvoter. I wasn't expecting there was so many such actions :)

Comment: @ŁukaszLech: Probably because the question is merely a curiosity one.

Comment: @RobertHarvey hmm looking [at this](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/114691?opt.textResults=true) its not clear (to me anyway) what the reasons where