# Statistics for good questions by time of day/day of week

Tags: discussion, statistics

I'm just curious, and I know the Stack Overflow guys often release data like this; is there any data or personal experience for which times of day / day of week / month of year produce the most interesting questions? I suppose data-wise that would translate to average upvotes per question asked.

Similarly, are there times when people are more likely to ask duplicate questions, etc.?

Comment: I don't really think total upvotes is a good measure of "good" or even "most interesting" questions.

Comment: @CodyGray it's just what I could think of. Any idea for a better metric? Maybe most answers? Most discussion? Most views (they're all a bit arbitrary)

Comment: Oh I know. I wasn't saying I have a better idea. It's very problematic to come up with a good data-based metric to evaluate this. The team tries to do this with the "Hot Questions" in the Super Multicollider Dropdown, but not everyone agrees with that algorithm (and that's putting it mildly). As a notable recent example, do you think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17807531/find-out-whos-going-to-buy-the-croissants) is extremely interesting?

Comment: @CodyGray that is an amazing question.

Comment: We need a [statiscs site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/175118/162730)!

Answer (score 2):

If you take upvotes as an indication for good questions (which is debatable but beyond the scope of my answer) you'll end-up with a graph like this for Stack Overflow:

[image: votes and questions per day]

You could conclude that asking wednesday (UTC) gives you a slightly better chance of upvotes while in the weekend you have a little bit more chance that grumpy down- and closevoters like myself vote on posts.

I used the following [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/296319#graph) to get that graph.

```sql
;with questions as 
( select datepart( dw, creationdate) as day
       , count(*) as [cnt]
       , (select count(*) 
          from posts 
          where posttypeid =1) as totcnt
from posts
where posttypeid = 1 -- Questions
group by datepart( dw, creationdate)
)
, qvotes as 
(
select datepart( dw, v.creationdate) as day
     , count(*) as [cnt]
     , sum( case when votetypeid = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as [up]
     , sum( case when votetypeid = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as [down]
     , sum( case when votetypeid = 6 then 1 else 0 end) as [close]
     , (select count(*)
        from votes v
        where votetypeid in (2,3,6)) as totvcnt
from votes v 
inner join posts p on p.id = v.postid and posttypeid =1 
where votetypeid in (2,3,6)
group by datepart( dw, v.creationdate)
)


select q.day
, ( cast(q.cnt as decimal) / cast(totcnt as decimal) * 100 ) as [q-cnt]
, (cast(v.cnt as decimal)/ cast(totvcnt as decimal)) * 100 as [v.qnt]
, (cast(v.up as decimal) / cast(v.cnt as decimal)) * 100 as [up]
, (cast(v.down as decimal) / cast(v.cnt as decimal)) * 100 as [down]
, (cast(v.[close] as decimal) / cast(v.cnt as decimal)) *100 as [close]
from questions q
inner join qvotes v on v.day = q.day
order by q.day
```

The [votes table](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/158100) creationdate column only holds the datepart, not the exact time a vote was casted. Due that we can't zoom-in in to best hour of the day.

You are free to fork my query and add the other stats you requested.