# Stackexchange data dump - Discrepancy of PostIDs in posts.xml and votes.xml

Tags: support, data-dump

I am inspecting the **stackexchange data dump** and found a discrepancy of PostIDs included in **posts.xml and votes.xml**.

It is obvious that there are some posts that do not have any voting activity.

My assumption was further that for every vote there should be a post in posts.xml. **However, in votes.xml are often PostIDs listed for which no post in posts.xml exists.**

Is that because when posts are deleted (due to various reasons) the votes for those posts are not deleted?

Here is an example:

For example, in anime.stackexchange.com.7z the votes.xml has 941 PostIDs that are not included in posts.xml, e.g. `"5"  "37" "47" "30" "52" "62"`.

You can quickly check this yourself by using the data explorer:

```
SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE Id = 5
SELECT * FROM Votes WHERE PostId = 5
```

Comment: Can you give a couple of examples of such PostIds (including the site)?

Comment: Sure. I updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). Deleted questions don't show in the Data Explorer and Data Dumps. If you visit https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/5, the question has been deleted by the author. Or https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/37 and it's been removed due to moderation.

It does beg the question, should the votes for a deleted post be in the data dump. That does confirm the existence of a post that has been deleted, so I'm not sure if that's a feature or a bug.

There is a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[to obtain metadata on deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157462). But it hasn't been touched for over a year.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It is reasonable that those posts are not included. However, I would agree that one should should think about deleting the corresponding votes.