# How to find deleted posts with highest votes

Tags: support, data-explorer

I'm writing query in data.stackexchange.com to find top 10 posts by score which are deleted. My query is this:

```
select top 10 a.PostId as [Post Link] from PostLinks a, posts b, postHistory c
where b.id=c.id and a.postId=b.id and PostHistoryTypeId=12
order by b.score desc
```

This gives the posts which are not deleted. What's wrong in my query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong<sup>1</sup> with your query, but deleted posts are not in the `posts` table on SEDE (or in the public datadump for that matter). In fact they are not available at all publicly.

Your join will not return records for deleted posts.

Also notice that `PostHistoryTypeId = 12` is only a vote to delete (as shown in the [Database schema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede)). It needs  3 votes from 20K users to be deleted (or one vote from a diamond).

If you think some statistical data about deleted posts should be available you might want to upvote [this feature request from december 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157462/can-some-metadata-about-deleted-posts-be-included-in-data-se)

<sub>1. although the join with `PostLinks` seems weird and unneeded given your requirements</sub>

Comment: How can I get deleted posts? In which table?

Comment: You can't. Deleted posts are not exported.