# How to get information about deleted users in Stack Exchange data dump?

Tags: support, data-explorer, data-dump

I was looking at Stack Exchange database and I wanted to know how to get the information about the deleted users. I didn't find any such information in [schema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede) of data dump. I specifically wanted to know about deleted users only. Can anyone please guide me so that I can get this information?

Comment: What "information" do you speak about?

Comment: What about a deleted user? They're deleted, so there's inherently not any information about them.

Comment: @animuson
Among many things, one thing I want to know is when users get deleted, the exact date.

Comment: @ᴡᴏʀᴅs
According to the answer given by Oded, everything about user get deleted most of the times(i.e. except the case when user is highly reputated). So how one can get to know about their usernames?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Can anyone please guide me so that I can get this information?

Data about deleted users doesn't exist in the data dump - the same way that data about deleted posts and deleted comments doesn't exist there (well, there is [some data about delete posts now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157462/can-some-metadata-about-deleted-posts-be-included-in-data-se/266431#266431) - but it is mostly metadata).

If you want a more complete set of data for research (to avoid survivor bias), you can contact Stack Exchange directly - it is possible that you can sign a contract to get access to such data. It will depend on what exactly you are trying to achieve and other factors and will likely require that you don't disclose any data that can identify people.

On a technical level - we hard delete users. We don't keep their information - unlike posts and comments that we soft delete so we can recover, user records are removed from the database. There is nothing that we can recover - they are gone.

Comment: The main thing I want to know is when a user get deleted. I don't require their names or anything. I just want to know that some person 'x' is deleted on this date and all such dates. Is this possible to gather??

Comment: @arman - we don't hold that information. Delete is delete.