# Outcome statistics for review queues

Tags: feature-request, review, statistics

Each review queue has a "stats" tab (and mods have access to an "advanced stats" link). The stats include the number of reviews completed for various cases: today, overall, by the user viewing the page, and a leaderboard for users.

But I'm a little surprised that there is no summary of outcomes.

- What fraction of question that go into the close-vote queue end up closed?
- How many are edited from the queue?
- How many are left open in the end?
- What fraction of first posts are OK? What fraction are bad?

Is there any reason to not compute and display a summary of outcomes of the review queues?

Answer (score 2):

Here are two SEDE queries which give some insight into the [outcome](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/529721/review-tasks-outcome) and the [individual actions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/529710/review-task-actions-by-one-user) of all review tasks on Stack Overflow in January of this year. Feel free to fork them if you need to do some trend analysis.

For close votes, there were 6,388 review tasks; 65% of the questions were closed, 32% were left open and 3% were edited. For the 52,259 first posts, 70% were deemed OK and 30% were 'reviewed' - but this includes reviews where the action was 'upvote' or 'add a comment'. I don't think further details are available for First Posts; you can't see them if you look at an [individual review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/13480511) either.

For reference, here are the queries:

```sql
SELECT tt.Name, rt.Name, rt.Description, COUNT(*)
  FROM ReviewTaskResults AS r
  INNER JOIN ReviewTaskResultTypes AS rt
    ON r.ReviewTaskResultTypeId = rt.Id
  INNER JOIN ReviewTasks AS t
    ON r.Id = t.CompletedByReviewTaskId
  INNER JOIN ReviewTaskTypes AS tt
    ON t.ReviewTaskTypeId = tt.Id
  WHERE r.CreationDate BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-02-01'
  GROUP BY tt.Name, rt.Name, rt.Description
  ORDER BY tt.Name, rt.Name
```

```sql
SELECT tt.Name, rt.Name, rt.Description, COUNT(*)
  FROM ReviewTaskResults AS r
  INNER JOIN ReviewTaskResultTypes AS rt
    ON r.ReviewTaskResultTypeId = rt.Id
  INNER JOIN ReviewTasks AS t
    ON r.ReviewTaskId = t.Id
  INNER JOIN ReviewTaskTypes AS tt
    ON t.ReviewTaskTypeId = tt.Id
  WHERE r.CreationDate BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-02-01'
  GROUP BY tt.Name, rt.Name, rt.Description
  ORDER BY tt.Name, rt.Name
```

Comment: Keep in mind that reviewtasks is sanitized. [It doesn't have deleted posts in it](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/529766/review-tasks-outcome)

Comment: @rene this probably means stats based on this table are useless. I briefly checked at SO where I'm under 10K so that my profile hides reviews for deleted posts allowing to compare these to my stats at review page: looks like about 3/4 of my reviews were on deleted posts. I doubt that stats based on such an incomplete data are reliable. Probably only SE developers can do sensible stats on that using their internal database and accessing deleted posts

Comment: @gnat yeah. I think we could make case that reviewtasks shouldn't be sanitized anymore. Let me see if there is an FR for that

Comment: @rene another option is to keep reviewtasks as is and add new table "reviewtaskswithdeleted" similar to how it was done when they [added PostsWithDeleted table](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266431/165773)

Comment: @gnat done here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283929/can-the-reviewtasks-table-include-the-reviews-for-deleted-posts-as-well