# Can the reviewtasks table include the reviews for deleted posts as well?

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

The table `reviewtasks` is [sanitized for deleted posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/529766/review-tasks-outcome). This means that it is hard, if not impossible, for the users that care and for those that want to evaluate the effectiveness of a community to find reliable statistics from [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) on completed reviewtasks.

If the data was available it would make it possible to answer [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283918/158100) for example.

Can the `reviewtasks` table be excluded from the process of removing rows that link to deleted posts? If that is not feasible can an extra table be introduced like `reviewtaskswithdeleted` similar to what is done with `postswithdeleted`, as suggested by [gnat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283918/outcome-statistics-for-review-queues/283928?noredirect=1#comment920484_283928).