# Is it possible to extract the history of deleted posts in SEDE?

Tags: support, data-explorer

I was writing an exploratory query to see what the average lifespan of questions which are closed as duplicates are then deleted, when I ran into a snag:  it doesn't seem like the `PostHistory` table contains any entries of posts which have been deleted.

Here's the exploratory query that I used:

```
SELECT Id [Post Link]
FROM PostsWithDeleted pwd
WHERE pwd.Id IN (
  SELECT PostId
  FROM PostHistory ph
  WHERE ph.PostHistoryTypeId = 10
        AND (ph.Comment = '1' OR ph.Comment = '101')
) AND pwd.DeletionDate IS NOT NULL;
```

I'm well aware that the magic Post Link will break under these circumstances, but it was there due to me fiddling with `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` in the database.

Is it the case that I can't go any further as a mere mortal?  If so, is there a specific reason that I don't have any further access to the post's history from SEDE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Jon Ericson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266431/), the answer is no: "there's no way to see the ClosedDate ... of deleted questions", which would be possible if they were present in PostHistory.

I infer from Jon's posts that the addition of PostsWithDeleted had no effect on other tables. In particular, PostHistory has what it always contained: the history of non-deleted posts. There is no PostHistoryWithDeleted.

Comment: Shoot.  That's what I had feared.  Thanks for finding that.