# Percentage of deleted posts per site

Tags: support, data-explorer, deleted-posts

I would like someone to post the ratio of deleted posts to total number of posts for each site, preferably computed over a recent time period such as the last three months.

Could someone please do a query and post the results so that I can view them on my cell phone?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can some metadata about deleted posts be included in Data.SE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157462/can-some-metadata-about-deleted-posts-be-included-in-data-se)

Comment: You are requesting effort from un-paid volunteers to spend their free time  in   a somewhat demanding tone of voice. Beyond that you didn't make it clear what you want those stats for. That makes your question not useful for future visitors, which is a reason to downvote.

Comment: @rene this is useful, but I didn't like the tone. It's the meta equivalent of "gimme teh codez!" request.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you're asking so nicely:

[Percentage of deleted posts, a networkwide comparison](https://data.stackexchange.com/apple/query/755112/percentage-of-deleted-post-a-networkwide-comparison?FromDate=2017-01-01&TillDate=2017-02-01)

Interestingly, Hardware Recommendations managed to get almost half of their posts from January 2017 deleted:

[image]

Codegolf Meta is probably on the list because of the heavily active [sandbox for proposed challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges); Graphic Design sees a lot of [spam posts](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/graphs) for a site of that size.

Comment: Actually OP didn't really ask nicely, it was more like "Give this to me" request. But still, well done! :)