# Results from SEDE's Posts is the same as PostsWithDeleted

Tags: support, data-explorer, deleted-posts, posts

The [SEDE](//data.stackexchange.com) is currently reporting the exact same results from `Posts` and `PostsWithDeleted`. For example,

- [Query from `Posts` by UserId](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1074210/posts-by-userid)
- [Query from `PostsWithDeleted` by UserId](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1074211/postswithdeleted-by-userid)

When I include the execution plan for the `Posts` query, it references the `PostWithDeleted` table:

[image]

Can this be fixed? Am I doing something wrong? Am I misinterpreting [what `PostWithDeleted` is supposed to contain](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2677/168244)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The field `owneruserid` is [sanitized for deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266431/158100) so it is expected if you run a query filtering on `owneruserid` that the results are the same.

It would be a bug if they were different.

You're misinterpreting the Database schema documentation.

> You find in Posts all non-deleted posts. PostsWithDeleted includes deleted posts while sharing the same columns with Posts but with only a few fields populated which **are marked with a 1 below**.

(emphasis mine)

The `OwnerUserid` doesn't have that 1.

[image: screenshot of creationdate, deletiondate and score having an superscript 1 while owneruseid does not have that 1]

Trying to make more clear what the functional difference is between those two tables I have update the text to:

> You find in `Posts` all non-deleted posts. `PostsWithDeleted` includes rows with deleted posts while sharing the same columns with `Posts` but [for deleted posts only a few fields populated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266431) which are marked with a <sup>1</sup> below.

That the execution plan shows the `PostsWithDeleted` table is caused by the fact that the `Posts` table is really a view over the `PostsWithDeleted` table. The query engine has no `Posts` table it can use to project that result from.

That view is created in the [`sp_Refresh_Database.sql`](https://gist.github.com/NickCraver/f009ab6e0d6b85ae54f6) near the end:

```
Declare @viewSql nvarchar(200) = 'Create View [Posts] As Select * From [PostsWithDeleted] Where DeletionDate Is Null';
Exec @dbSql @viewSql;
```

That specific stored procedure is run on each weekly refresh.

Comment: So there's no way of identifying someone's deleted posts... that seems strange. Any reason why `OwnerUserId` wasn't kept?

Comment: @Werner it isn't kept as you can only find those deleted posts if you know the id, or are the owner and have > 10K (in which case isdeleted:1 will work in search). Only mods can find deleted posts for a specific user. So what is available in SEDE mimics what is available on the sites for every user. Before that SEDE gets more data I expect the functionality on the sites to find deleted posts need to be expanded. Or you become a mod, or an SE employee...