# Block "enter image description here"

Tags: feature-request, images, alt-text

Soooo many people don't bother following the simple instructions filled in automatically for alt text ([old stats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/88763/155739)). Posts are rife with "enter image description here" which leaves content inaccessible for the visually impaired.

I realise that in many cases *we cannot prevent this* — lazy peeps will be lazy.

However, if we block post submission when images are present with "enter image description here" and prompt people to provide real image descriptions, we *may* improve results by some percentage. Sure, some will just try to enter an empty string (block that too!) or some meaningless nonsense. But surely others will go "ah, okay, I should do that".

Worth an experiment?

Comment: Blocking is probably too strong, but I'm fairly certain a message can help a lot too. I myself sometimes just forget image descriptions.

Comment: At least the current default text could be changed to "ENTER IMAGE DESCRIPTION HERE" (although I dislike shouting in most other cases).

Comment: I really don't get what's so difficult about, y'know, entering the image description there!

Comment: No, no matter how irritating it can get (and it does), blocking is wrong. It would drive people away, and we have more than enough things that drive people away already. -1

Comment: See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310628/avoiding-enter-image-description-here) for similar request that doesn't ask to forcibly block. (Which IMO is better)

Comment: @ShaWiz One of the options there is as I've suggested here - but yes that looks like a dupe, d'oh!

Comment: Enter comment description here.

Comment: ^%$@!)( I tried to do the right thing [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/330562/158100) only to find out that in my browser (Chrome) the alt text isn't shown at all. Why do we even have a feature that is half broken?

Comment: @rene I don't follow. Where were you expecting to see the alt text? Alt text is for screenreaders (and for when the image is unavailable) neither of which is true for you (if you're using Chrome). Are you confusing alt text with titletext/tooltips?

Comment: @rene Thanks for adding alt text to your post!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yes, I'm confusing alt and title attributes. Thanks for being my guide ;)

Comment: @Scheff: Or alternatively, the current default text could be changed to *"**PLEASE** ENTER IMAGE DESCRIPTION HERE. **THANKS IN ADVANCE**."* 